# Slim Php Frame work V2 to V4 Route conditions

Tags: php, slim

I am Updating my PHP slim version from v2 to v4 which project was created long ago

i have a doubt on setting conditions for group route in slim v4

here is my group route code in v2

```
$app->group('/routeone/{paramone}', function (RouteCollectorProxy $group) {       

    $group->get('/routetwo', Controller::class . '{param}')->conditions(array('paramone' => paramone value));
    $group->get('/route3', Controller::class . '{param}')->conditions(array('paramone' => paramone value));
    $group->get('/route4', Controller::class . '{param}')->conditions(array('paramone' => paramone value));
    $group->get('/route5/{paramtwo}', Controller::class . '{param}')->conditions(array('paramone' => paramone value));

});
```

after changing the route to v4 the condition method returns as undefined in vs code

can any one help me with equivalent condition method for slim v4 i read about the docs for condition but did not find any docs regarding  that

Comment: I guess you can use [regular expression matching](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html#regular-expression-matching) to get similar functionality in v4.

Comment: but how to set regex for array and how to do it for group routes

Comment: Something like: `/routeone/{paramone:regex-to-match-here}`. Don't know what you mean by "set regex for array". You simply define the regex for the route parameter when you define it instead of calling a method after.